# how to disable IIS Certificate validation

Tags: c#, iis-7, httpwebrequest

I have a certificate bind with my website which is deploy on IIS.

How can I use the website by using an invalid certificate?

By invalid I mean that either *hostname* or *IP address* don't match with the system.

Comment: To me knowledge, IIS does not validate the certificate. The client browser does.

Comment: I have use <system.net> <settings> <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false" checkCertificateRevocationList="false" /> </settings> </system.net> In Web.config but it is not working

Comment: Error Message in logs : The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: Settings in IIS will not matter. This is a validation step done in the browser.

Comment: Instead of asking this, you should search for how to suppress certificate warning in the browser. Your changes to web.config won't work either, as that's strictly for .NET side certificate validation, not for the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The inscure certificate warning is returned from browser side instead of IIS side. If you just need a certificate for internal use and want web browser no longer alert warning , then you can generate a custom self-signed certificate with certutil.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjaminperkins/make-your-own-ssl-certificate-for-testing-and-learning

I think it is insecure to remove that warning from your web browser.

Comment: I have use 

    <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false" checkCertificateRevocationList="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>

In Web.config but it is not working

Comment: Error Message in logs : The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.